# Passphrase-protected private key and automatic server directory mounting

Tags: ssh, fstab, authentication, sshfs, passphrase

I am learning sshfs on ubuntu 20.04, that is the client machine.

I have turned on SSH key-based authentication.

The Public key has been already stored on my server.

I set the passphrase for protecting my private key.

Now when I manually execute sshfs command on terminal to mount any server's directory, it asks me to enter the passphrase for enabling to access my private key.

Then I have a question.

Do I need to turn off the passphrase protection for my private key if I want to automatically mount a directory of my server by sshfs on booting my client system?

I added the line below to /etc/fstab, but it does not work.

`user@host:/remote/dir  /local/mountpoint  fuse.sshfs  defaults  0  0`

The above line from "How to use SSHFS to Mount Remote Directories over SSH"
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-directories-over-ssh/

I want to know any solution to achieve automatic server directory mounting with keeping secureness.

Comment: I've arrived at the same question - what was your solution?